# How to use an Elevated Button Theme from a themes file?

Tags: flutter, dart

Since raised buttons are deprecated in favor of ElevatedButtons, I haven't been able to find any clear examples on using an ElevatedButtonTheme from another file.

Elevated buttons accept a style property, a button style specifically, but this style property does not accept an elevatedButtonTheme object which is what common sense says should work. The button style wants MaterialState properties, nothing mentioning an elevatedButtonTheme :(.

[image]

Can someone provide an example for this? The docs do not make it clear, there are no examples here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ElevatedButtonTheme-class.html

Answer (score 1):

```
style: Theme.of(context).elevatedButtonTheme.style?.copyWith(
  backgroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.blueGrey),
  // other properties
),
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Flutter's default behavior is that it will automatically default to the elevatedButtonTheme, there's no need to specify it. I just needed to specify the correct color in my theme file and it started working. There was no need to specify a style property.

> The elevated button's default style is defined by defaultStyleOf. The style of this elevated button can be overridden with its style parameter. The style of all elevated buttons in a subtree can be overridden with the ElevatedButtonTheme, and the style of all of the elevated buttons in an app can be overridden with the Theme's ThemeData.elevatedButtonTheme property.

from - https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ElevatedButton-class.html